# How to group content and sticky sidebar to center in webpage?

Tags: html, css

Im making a mock-up of a website and I want to have the content and a sticky sidebar to follow it. I want it to be compatible across screen of all sizes, so I want it to be centered no matter the screen size.

Here's my HTML pertaining to the relevant part:

```
<div class="sticky">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username"> 
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>

<div class = "content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class = "content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class = "content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class = "content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.sticky{
position: sticky;
top: 45px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
margin-right: 3%;
margin-top: 10px;
height:150px;
width:190px;    
border:1px solid black;
padding:10px;
}
.sticky input{
padding:5px;
margin:5px
}

.content{
    font-family: Verdana;
    width: 870px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 5px ;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;  
}

.content a{
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

So how do I 'group' them so it can all be centered?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```css
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 45px;
  float: none;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  height: 190px;
  width: 190px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sticky input {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px
}

.content-container {
  //position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.content {
  font-family: Verdana;
  width: 98vw;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content a {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="content"><a href="#">Lorem</a>ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

Are you sure about `position: sticky`? It would be a little weird. You can see it better here: https://jsfiddle.net/vtzgp6sb/1/
You can also try this:

```
.content-container {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```